# Outlook Recurrence events content issue

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I created a recurrence event in Outlook. Then I edited each event individually to include URLs in the content. After that I changed the time for the whole recurrence events and I was shocked that all the content of each event has disappeared. Why?  And is there a better way to include URLs in recurrence events (for each event different URLs) and when updating the time the content will not be affected?

Answer (score 0):

Can you find items on the webmail?  Besides, try turning off the caching option in the Outlook shared folders on Windows can troubleshoot the problem.

To do it, open your Outlook for Windows and choose the Tools or File Menu. Launch Account Settings after it. Choose your Exchange Account and click the change button. Now hit the More settings button. Select the second Advanced tab.

"Download shared folders" should be unchecked. Confirm your action by OK and restart the application.

Comment: I am writing to see how everything is going on with this thread.